# How do you clean up redundant values in a list of lists

Tags: python, sublist

Say I have a list of list
`X=[[0,0,0,3,4],[8,8,9,2,8,2]]`

How do I make it so that each sublist will only contain a repeated number once:
Like this new list:

`XNew=[[0,3,4],[8,9,2]]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `set` for that:

```
new_x = [list(set(i)) for i in old_x]
```

Sets are a collection of unique elements and therefore create a set of unique values when a list of duplicate values is cast as a set. You can then convert the set back to a list and get the desired result.

#### Example

```
>>> old_x = [[0,0,0,3,4],[8,8,9,2,8,2]]
>>> new_x = [list(set(i)) for i in old_x]
>>> print new_x
[[0,3,4],[8,9,2]]
```

Comment: for what it's worth, I would not convert back from `set` to `list` in any of my own code, unless there was some compelling reason for it; `set`s can be used for virtually all of the same things as lists.

Comment: Keep in mind that sets are unordered by design, so you shouldn't use sets if you need to keep the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the order of your numbers, you can't use sets. This would keep the original order:

```
lst = [[0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [8, 8, 9, 2, 8, 2]]
new_lst = []

for sub_lst in lst:
    seen = set()
    new_sub = []
    for item in sub_lst:
        if item not in seen:
            new_sub.append(item)
            seen.add(item)
    new_lst.append(new_sub)

print new_lst # [[0, 3, 4], [8, 9, 2]]
```